# Updating drivers from Device Manager (remote)

Tags: windows

Is it possible to add/update drivers in device manager on a server using the device manager mmc snap-in from a workstation?

Comment: why not rdp in to the server?

Comment: Im using server 2008 r2 core

Comment: well you can rdp to server core and at that point you can use the pnputil to update the driver.

Comment: Device Manager is read only when used remotely so you won't be able to make any configuration changes thru it :(.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can rdp to server core and at that point you can use the pnputil to update the driver.